# How to findAll query where value is from associated table in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize as my ORM and I want to know the best way to achieve the desired outcome.
With the models below, how do I return an array that returns all the Books and Novels while removing duplicates that have the same author+title.

```
    var Book = sequelize.define('Book', {

        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        author: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
        //....other columns
    })

    var Novel = sequelize.define('Novel', {

        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        author: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
        //...other different columns 
    })
```

Comment: If you have one Book and one Novel with the same author and title which one should be a duplicate? Book or Novel?

Comment: @Anatoly It should be in book, and not in novel.

Comment: You can query all novels and books and then use something like the lodash package and its unionBy function to get unique novels and books. Novels must be the first array.